# wp_get_referer store in session

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I need to display a text in the header if the user comes from site1.com. Now I have a working one Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$referer = wp_get_referer();
if ( $referer == "http://site1.com" ) {

  echo '<span class="referrer-display"> <a href="http://site1.com">RETURN TO SITE1.COM</a> </span></p>';

} else {

  echo "";

}
?>
```

The problem is when the user transfer to another page the text is removed. I believe it has something to do with session? Please enlighten me or point me to the correct direction to achieve what I want.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Referer gets removed because when you click to another link, the referer is not the same. Referer is the page on which you clicked to get to that page. You can keep the referer data inside session to preserve the value.

Comment: Hi,I agree with the session. But can you somewhat give me an example or reference? I've read online several manuals but not giving me the correct result.

Comment: Get the referer the way you already have it. Get it at the main page. After that, ensure that WP already has session_start(); somewhere, if it does, just add a line $_SESSION['referer'] = $yourReferer; Now you can access it from every page as long as the session is not destroyed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help it turns out the best way is to use cookie rather than session.